# How to create Array of custom object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

```
module NameSpacens{
    interface Serializable<T> {
        deserialize(input: Object): T;
    }

    export class Class1 implements Serializable<Class1>{
        private prop1: number;
        private prop2:string;
        constructor(va1?:number, va2?:string){
            this.prop1 = va1;
            this.prop2 = va2;
        }

        deserialize(jsonData){
            if (!(Array.isArray(jsonData))) {
                this.Index = jsonData.index;
                this.HeaderName = jsonData.headerName;
                this.SortName = jsonData.sortName;
                this.AllowSorting = jsonData.allowSorting;
                return this;
            }
            else {
                //How to code this portion to create list?
            }
        }
    }
}

var jsonDatas = [{ prop1: 1, prop2: "Test1"}, { prop1: 2, prop2: "Test2" }];

var coll:Array<NameSpacens.Class1> = new NameSpacens.Class1().deserialize(jsonDatas);
```

for coll I am getting below error during compile time.

Type 'Class1' is not assignable to type 'Class1[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Class1'.

Also how I can create the list from JSON array of objects, in this case jsonDatas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to have a function inside the class that initializes objects, that's what constructors are for.

Instead you can iterate over the **jsonDatas** array and create a new class instance for every one of them.

You can easily do it with a **map** call.

```js
module NameSpacens{

    export class Class1 {

        constructor(private prop1?:number, private prop2?:string){

        }


    }
}

var jsonDatas = [{ prop1: 1, prop2: "Test1"}, { prop1: 2, prop2: "Test2" }];

var coll:Array<NameSpacens.Class1> = jsonDatas.map((data) => new NameSpacens.Class1(data.prop1, data.prop2));
```

Comment: Oh, you'll probably not need the Serializable interface either.